# WHMCS is just a blank white?

Tags: integration, whmcs

I'm editing my theme in WHMCS and for some reason the site is just a blank white. I cleared my cache but it didn't help.  I'm not sure why this is happening.

http://bluminati.tk/whmcs

Comment: Nvm guys.. I needed toa dd the rest of the js to the footer.. the page is working now :D can i delete this somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blank page in the WHMCS indicates a fatal PHP error is occurring.

http://docs.whmcs.com/Blank_Pages